# composer laravel install: "http://packagist.org" file could not be downloaded

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php, backend

I want to install laravel 2.2 through composer with

```
$ composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel sampleBackend 5.2
```

but every time i do that composer shows a message:

> The
>   "http://packagist.org/p/provider-2014%2490c266c2df21924a932e564b7f39bf03d55b933fbe43744a6056eab59b7b4cf9.json"
>   file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed! http://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package
>   information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date

Comment: try running `composer clearcache` first

Comment: Can you access the given URL using your browser? Can you `wget` the URL on the server where you are running `composer`?

Comment: yes the url is working in the browser and the wget so what's the problem with composer?

Answer (score 1):

Clear composer cache first by running

```
composer clear-cache
```

Then run this command

```
composer -vvv
```

This solution worked for me when I was trying to install laravel.